# Is it okay to rename programs in the usr/local/bin directory? I renamed code to vsc

Tags: shell, unix, visual-studio-code

I just installed Visual Studio Code and I installed a CLI tool that allowed me to open Visual Studio Code from the terminal using the command `code`

I decided I wanted to change this to `vsc` so it'd be similar to the `subl` shortcut that I have for sublime text. I realized I could change the shortcut name by going to my `usr/local/bin` directory and simply changing the name of `code` to `vsc`.

I was wondering if changing the name from code to vsc could cause me any problems in the future such as when i install certain extensions or update Visual Studio Code.

Should I be fine or are there more modifications I need to do to make my new terminal shortcut stable?

Comment: Don't change the original name (it is always a bad idea), but add some link/symbolic link/alias, etc.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Do you have any idea of why it may not work in the future? Are there any resources you'd recommend to learn more about the terminal / sys admin stuff?

Comment: Too difficult to answer, in theory you should be able to rename/move the executable where you want, but sometimes, some tools need your application to be installed in a given way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should use an alias, something like:

```
alias vsc="/usr/local/bin/code"
```

Although your way may work now, there is guarantee that it will continue to work in the future - this goes with any undocumented feature in any app.

Comment: Do you have any idea of why it may not work in the future? Are there any resources you'd recommend to learn more about the terminal / sys admin stuff?

Comment: It might not work in the future because developers are crazy beings and the developers VSCode may say, "ok, we now need to invoke VSCode from the terminal", "sure, what is the path?", "its bla bla, and its undocumented so we don't *need* to flag it as a breaking change, lets just invoke it". Essentially its hard enough keeping a public/documented api/pathset/etc consistent, nearly no developer would try to keep a private one consistent - it wouldn't be time efficient or productive